# Can't Install VNC Server on Mac Catalina OS X 10.15.6 "Installation Failed"

Tags: installation, vncserver

I can't get VNC Server 6.7.2 to install on Catalina OS X 10.15.6. It says error during installation each time. I've tried re-downloading the installer, and tried several previous versions with no luck. I also tried installing via Terminal with no luck either. It says "must be run as root" but I'm not sure what that means. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Update: I was able to install via terminal by adding "sudo" to command. However, the VNC Server app fails to launch, which I'll have to figure out.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem. It looked like vnc was already running but I couldn't see it.

Try this:

1. Open the terminal
2. Execute this exact command: `sudo /Library/vnc/vncserver -QuitOnCloseStatusDialog`

This will make the already running vnc visible in the status bar.
I hope it works for you.